# Creating something where screen was tapped? Swift

Tags: swift

The basic idea is that I want the user to tap somewhere within a UIView, not anywhere on the screen and be taken to another page to create the content of a text label or button that'd play an audio file.

1. Tap on screen
2. Create something
3. Thing created shows up in the UIView where you had tapped

Even some pseudo code to get me pointed in the right direction would be appreciate.

Comment: You ask two different things: the first in the phrase where you ask to go to another page after the user tap, and in the third point of your list where you ask to show the tap results in the same view where user has tapped. I don't know what do you real want to do but I've follow the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `TapGestureRecognizer` on your ViewController and connect its `viewTapped` action to your function. Since the gesture recognizer is owned by the ViewController you need to detect if the tapped point on the screen is within your target view.

Code snippet to get you started:
`self.view` is the ViewController´s view.
`self.targetView` is the target view within the ViewController.

```
@IBAction func viewTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // detect the tapped view
    let loc = tapGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.targetView.frame, loc)) {
        // the target view was tapped
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We start with the following `UIView` that contain a `UILabel`:

```
class Controller1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var discCoverView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var listenToMeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let discoCoverViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(Controller1.discoCoverViewTap(_:)))
        self.discCoverView.addGestureRecognizer(discoCoverViewGesture)
    }   

    func discoCoverViewTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       // detect the location tapped by user
       let tapLocation = tapGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.discCoverView)
       if self.listenToMeLabel.frame.contains(tapLocation) {
           // user tap the listenToMeLabel
           let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let controller2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("controller2") as Controller2
           controller2.songTitle = self.listenToMeLabel.text
           self.presentViewController(controller2, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
    }
}
```

The Controller2 can be:

```
import AVFoundation
class Controller2: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var listenToMeBtn: UIButton!
      var songTitle: String! = "no title"

      override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
          super.viewDidAppear(animated)
          listenToMeBtn.setTitle(songTitle, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
          listenToMeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Controller2.listenToMeBtnTap(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
          listenToMeBtn.setNeedsLayout()
      }

      func listenToMeBtnTap(sender:UIButton) {
          print ("click \(sender.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal))")
          let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(songTitle, withExtension: "mp3")
          if (url == nil) {
             print("Could not find song file: \(songTitle)")
             return
          }
          do { backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: nil) }
          catch let error as NSError { print(error.description) }

          if let player = backgroundMusicPlayer {
             player.volume = 0.7
             player.prepareToPlay()
             player.play()  
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
     override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) { 
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        let newView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 100,100)
        newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(newView)
    }
}
```